# Why are my Windows (10) windows slow to move first time?

Tags: windows

I don't know if its my machine(s) but when I select a window in Windows 10 and move it across the screen it often doesn't move first time.  I have to let go of the mouse left button and re select it. I don't know if this is Microsoft problem or some setting somewhere but my computer is new and it happens randomly.

Any ideas ? THANKS !

**edit. Specs of my two laptops : One is a 1 year old Dell XPS 15. 16GB RAM, 512 GB SSD. The other is an 5 year old HP DV6 laptop but also has a 512GB SSD, and 8GB RAM and both run Windows 10.  Both laptops run Visual Studio 2017 quickly and don't have speed issues.

Comment: What are the specs of the machine(s)? I've never seen this personally so I'd suspect some slow or sluggish hardware.

Comment: You say machine(s). Which is it?

Comment: I have a Dell XPS 15. 16GB RAM, 512 GB SSD. the other is an older machine but also has a SSD, and 8GB RAM. Its like the windows are frosty, once i miss I have to go back and do the same maneuver again

Comment: Try a different mouse... sounds like a buggy mouse to me so I'd easily very or eliminate that as the cause as a starting point.

Comment: no I am using a Cooler Master, its something buggy with Windows. The window - usually an explorer (files) refuses to move first time and I have to wait about a second or two. its definitely a windows bug

Comment: Have you checked for and installed updated drivers and system firmwares?